# How to let the array know if there is a non-numeric input or it reaches the end of input?

Tags: c, arrays, average, alphabet

I've made an array program that reads in 10 numbers and finds the minimum, maximum, and average of those numbers.

Now, I want the program to print out "There's not enough numbers" when it encounters non-numeric input or it reaches the end of input. e.g. 3 65 2 4 hello -> "There's not enough numbers"

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 10

int main (void) {

int array [LENGTH];
int i, max, min, sum;
float average;

printf("Enter vector of 10 numbers: ");

// inputting the numbers into an array

for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &array [i]);
}

// Finding the minimum value
min = array [0];
for(i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    if(min > array [i]) {
        min = array [i];
    }
}

printf("Minimum vector is %d\n", min);

// Finding the maximum value
max = array [0];
for(i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    if(max < array [i]) {
        max = array [i];
    }
}

printf("Maximum vector value is %d\n", max);

// Finding the average of all values
sum = 0;
average = 0;
for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
    sum = sum + array [i];
    average = sum / LENGTH;
}

printf("Average vector value is %.1f\n", average); // %.1f prints the number with 1 decimal point


return 0;
```

}

Comment: [This `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might come in handy. Check what the function(s) *return*.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns the number of tokens successfully parsed.

Here is an example on how to check if input is successful:

```
// inputting the numbers into an array
for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &array [i])) {
        printf("Not enough values!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets` and `strtol`:

```
char str[32];
char *ptr;

for (i = 0; i < LENGTH;) {
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        array[i] = (int)strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
        if (ptr != str && *ptr == '\n') {
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("Enter a valid number\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear - what is the value of `ptr &&` in `if (ptr && *ptr == '\n') {`?  I do not see how `ptr` would every be `NULL`.

Comment: @chux, `strtol()`stores the address of the first invalid character in `*ptr`, if the first not valid character is a newline then we have a valid number, there was a bug in the first version you are right `ptr` must be compared with `str` not with `NULL`(If there were no digits at all, `strtol()` stores the original value), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution, in the for loop

```
  while (i!=LENGTH){

puts("There's no enough numbers");

}
```

this can discover the end of the array

To discover if there are non numeric value, i thing you have to use a built in function like for example `IsDigit` which is a function to test if there is a digit or not.